# Almost sure convergence of the sum of random variables divided by their expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $(X_i)_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent random variables (but not identically distributed) with $0\leq X_i\leq 1$ for all $i\ge1.$ Let $S_{n} = X_{1}+\dots +X_{n}$. Prove that $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} \to 1\:\:\text{a.s.}$

**Thoughts:** I originally wanted to prove that $\mathbb{P}(|S_n-\mathbb{E}[S_n]|>\delta\:\:\text{i.o.}) = 0$. One would then need $\sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(|S_n-\mathbb{E}[S_n]|>\delta) < \infty$. However, I am unable to obtain an upper bound on the sum since the random variables are not identically distributed. Any hints?

Comment: Is $S_{n} = X_{1}+\dots +X_{n}$ or did you mean to write $X_{n}$ instead of $S_{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of solving this problem (there may be easier methods out there). We have $0\leq X_{i}^{2}\leq X_{i}\leq 1$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, 
$$\text{Var}(S_{n}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\text{Var}(X_{i})\leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{i}^{2}]\leq\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{i}] = \mathbb{E}[S_{n}]$$
The idea is to show that a subsequence of the original sequence converges $\text{a.s.}$ which we shall show is sufficient. Let
$$n_{k} = \min\{n:\mathbb{E}[S_{n}]\geq k^{2}\}\:\:\:\:k = 1, 2, \dots$$
Since $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}]\leq 1$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ we have $k^{2}\leq \mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]\leq k^{2}+1$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ then by the Chebyshev inequality
$$\mathbb{P}(|S_{n_{k}}-\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]| > \varepsilon\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}])\leq\frac{\text{Var}(S_{n_{k}})}{\varepsilon^{2}\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2}\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2}k^{2}}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_{n_{k}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}-1\right|> \varepsilon\right) < \infty$$
Using the First Borel Cantelli Lemma
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_{n_{k}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}-1\right|> \varepsilon\:\:\text{i.o.}\right) = 0\implies \frac{S_{n_{k}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}\rightarrow 1\:\:\text{a.s.}$$
We now show that this is sufficient. Let $n_{k}\leq n\leq n_{k+1}$ then
$$\frac{S_{n}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n}]}\leq \frac{S_{n_{k+1}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}\cdot\frac{{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k+1}}]}}{{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k+1}}]}}\leq \frac{S_{n_{k+1}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k+1}}]}\cdot \frac{(k+1)^2+1}{k^2}$$
In a similar manner we obtain a lower bound
$$\frac{S_{n}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n}]}\geq \frac{S_{n_{k}}}{\mathbb{E}[S_{n_{k}}]}\cdot \frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2+1}$$
The result then follows by taking the $\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}$ and $\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}$ of the previous inequalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This method seems so useful

Comment: Shi Hao, you're welcome.

Comment: Hi,Karthik Kannan. Can you help me with another question? （https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462991/limiting-distribution-about-poisson）

Comment: Hi, Kevin Liu, I am currently a student of probability theory too and it seems I haven't learned enough theory to answer your question.