# Limiting distribution about Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2...X_n \sim U(0,1)$ be $i.i.d $, $S_n=\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m$, please find the limiting distribution of $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \mathbb I_{X_m S_n\leq1}$.

I guess that might be Poisson distribution. And Let $Y_{m,n}= \mathbb I_{X_m S_n\leq1}$ and want to verify the two conditions for Possion convergence theorem. The first condition is that we need $\sum_{m=1}^{n}p_{m,n} \to \lambda.$ Actually $p_{m,n} \leq P(X_m\leq \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}-\delta)n})+P(\frac{S_n}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}-\delta)$, when summation, I have no idea how to control the second term. Can you give me some hint or another method?

Comment: i think the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb I_{X_m S_n\leq1}$ should be $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \mathbb I_{X_m S_n\leq1}$

Comment: Thank for your reminding me of the typos

Comment: @Kevinliu Where is this problem coming from? Is this a textbook exercise?

Comment: one problem in qualify examination of our department in 2010

Comment: To control $n P(S_n\leq n/2-\delta n)$, use Hoeffding's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables.

Comment: @NCh Thanks a lot. The inequality works.